# ScrollViewer disappear automatically in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

i have an items control that is bound to an observable collection of videos.I added a vertical scroll bar but but it disappear after the page is loaded.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="_imageList" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="-1,0"  Width="460"  >
    <ItemsControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <ItemsPresenter />
            </ScrollViewer>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Template>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <UniformGrid Columns="4" Rows="3"/>
                    <!--<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>-->
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                <Button Click="btn_Clicked" Margin="9,9,9,9" BorderThickness="0"  Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}">
                <Image x:Name="image" Source="{Binding thumbnail}"   ClipToBounds="True"/>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

This is code behind of my page:

```
 public void Images()
    {
        var images = new ObservableCollection<Video>();
        var wcf = new ServiceReferenceVideo.VideoServiceClient();
        link_thumb = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var item in wcf.GetAllVideos())
        {
            images.Add(item);
        }
        _imageList.ItemsSource = images;
    }
```

Comment: I might be missing it but I don't see where you set the `ItemsSource` for the ItemsControl. Also, could you describe how you add content to your `ObservableCollection`? Could you describe what content it shows and which content it does not show?

Comment: _imageList.ItemsSource = images; in the code behind and images is an ObservableCollection<Video>

Comment: Hint: You can click the `edit` button under the question and add it directly to your question.

Comment: ohh please this is not the question.The ItemsControls works just fine but i can't scroll all the items :this is what i want to know.

Comment: What I know is that an ItemsControl with a Scrollbar should be able to scroll all its items just fine. So my intuition tells me that there is something up with how you add items to your control and maybe also when. But that is impossible to know without seeing how you do just that, correct? This is why I would like to see that as well included in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wont work because your `UniformGrid` automatically adopts to the available size. Try set a fixed `Width` or `MinWidth` like `300` for the buttons in your `DataTemplate`

Here is a working example:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="525"
    Height="350">
<Grid>

    <ItemsControl x:Name="Items">
        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
                <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <ItemsPresenter />
                </ScrollViewer>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Columns="4"
                             IsItemsHost="True"
                             Rows="3" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button MinWidth="200"
                        MinHeight="200"
                        Margin="9"
                        Content="{Binding }" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Items.ItemsSource = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(0,100));
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just an example on how you make your UniformGrid Scroll with simplified data (numbers instead of images). Put it into a standard WPF Application and you will see what I mean. Your Scrollbar does disappear, because the UniformGrid takes all available size and scales its content to it. So in your case there is no necessaty for WPF to render your ScrollBar. If you put a fixed Width/Height or MinWidth/Height onto you Images, the Desired Size of the content will be larger then available space, so WPF finally adds your scrollviewer with scrollbars.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the Scrollviewer outside the ItemsControl. Something like...

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <ItemsControl>
    </ItemsControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Right.  `ScrollViewer` is not a scrollbar. It's a control that scrolls its contents.

Comment: But his ControlTemplate already has a ScrollViewer which is wrapping the ItemsPresenter. Why would he need one outside the itemscontrol?